# How can I get exact user plus the user's exact posts in laravel from jwt token

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

I'm trying to get the logged in users details by sending the jwt into the headers, but I also want to get the user's details in another table.
I want to see the user's details plus the user's post in another table as well.
This the function

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    // the token is valid and we have found the user via the sub claim

    $user = auth()->user();
    $userid = User::where('id', $user->id)->first();
    $return = UserResource::collection($userid);   
    return response()->json($return);


}
```

This is the error message

```
<!--
BadMethodCallException: Call to undefined method App\User::mapInto() in file C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 50

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php(36): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::throwBadMethodCallException('mapInto')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(1620): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->forwardCallTo(Object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder), 'mapInto', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\CollectsResources.php(30): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__call('mapInto', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection.php(52): Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection->collectResource(Object(App\User))
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection.php(25): Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\ResourceCollection->__construct(Object(App\User))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource.php(78): Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection->__construct(Object(App\User), 'App\\Http\\Resour...')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\app\Http\Controllers\getUserController.php(67): Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource::collection(Object(App\User))
#7 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\getUserController->getAuthenticatedUser()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\doc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
```

While this is the App\User (user model)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Auth;


class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail, JWTSubject
{
    use Notifiable;
    public function __construct()
        {

            Auth::shouldUse('users');
        }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'phone', 'password', 'Age', 'Blood', 'Gender', 'Height', 'Weight', 'picture', 'history', 'record',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }


    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }


    public function appointment(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment');
    }
}
```

What is the possible fix?

Comment: No clue what youre trying to do; why do you have this `getAuthenticatedUser` function because im guessing that these checks are already in the auth guard of Tymon JWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) about resource collections.

You can see they are using `User::all()`. You on the other hand are using `User::where('id', $user->id)->first();`. The difference between those is the return value. `all()` returns a `Collection`, `first()` returns (in this case) a single `User` instance.

The error you are getting already tells you what is wrong. "Call to undefined method App\User::mapInto()". It tries to call `mapInto` on a `User`. However [`mapInto`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-mapinto) is a method of `Collection`.

Knowing this we could do things depening what you want.

Do you want to return multiple users?

```
UserResource::collection(User::all());
```

Do you want to return one user?

```
// You already have user from auth()->user(). No need to refetch it.
new UserResource(auth()->user());
```

For adding the posts of the user I suggest you take a look at [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) a relationship and [conditionally adding](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships) it to the `UserResource`.

Eager loading and conditionally adding a relationship are not required in this scenario, but I highly suggest to do this guessing you might use the `UserResource` also for returning multiple `User` instances.